# Passing data from embedded PageViewController to parent View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller

I'm working on an app that includes a "Representative Finder" that will allow someone to enter their address in a UITextField or select a state from a PickerView to see their government representatives. I have a main ViewController that will display the results after a user submits one of the aforementioned options. Over this, I have imposed a ContainerView into which I have embedded a PageViewController that has two pages; one that includes a UITextField and button to search by address, and the other that includes a PickerView and a Button that searches by state. The PageView is currently connected to the TableView via an embed transition, however, when I try to reference the parent table view controller in the PageViewController, it says the PVC has no parent, even though the ViewController identifies the PageViewController as its child. My question is: what is the proper way to pass variables FROM a child PageViewController to its container?

EDIT: I've tried the following, but it doesn't work:

In my PageViewController:

```
protocol SearchFinderDelegate: class
{
    func getResults(results: String)
}

class LawSearchWindow: UIPageViewController
{
     weak var newDelegate: SearchFinderDelegate?

  viewDidLoad()
   {

       /*Attempt to initialize newDelegate*/
       newDelegate=self
       newDelegate?.getResults(results: “test123”)
  }}
```

And in my Main VC class, I have:

```
func getResults(results: String)
{
    print(results)
}
```

UPDATE: When I try make the 'newDelegate=self' declaration, it tells me 'Cannot assign value of type 'VC name' to type 'Delegate Name'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper way would be to create a delegate protocol and have the parent conform to it (which the child then has a reference to as a weak property) or pass in a completion handler callback block to the child and have the child call that. Generally, you don't want to be directly referencing a parent from its child.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still a little new to this and I can't seem to get it to work. In my PVC, I have the following:

protocol SearchFinderDelegate
{
    func getResults(results: String)
}

class LawSearchWindow
{
var newDelegate: SearchFinderDelegate?

viewDidLoad()
{
 newDelegate?.getResults(results: “test123”)
}

And in my Main VC, I have the following:

It conforms to SearchFinderDelegate

in the class, I have

func getResults(results: String)
{
 print(results)
}

I can’t seem to get the “results” string to print from the main VC

Comment: You should edit your original post with all the relevant code, properly formatted.

Comment: Looks like you didn't actually initialize a value for `newDelegate`. Is it set to the parent or is it nil?

Comment: The guides I have read say to not initialize it. What would be the proper way to initialize it in this case?

Comment: You have to give it a value for you to be able to do anything with it, what would you expect to happen otherwise? The easiest thing would be to set the property after you create your `LawSearchWindow` object by just doing something like `myLawSearchWindow.newDelegate = self` assuming `self` is your actual `SearchFinderDelegate`

Comment: Just tried this (and updated above) and got an "EXC_BAD_ INSTRUCTION" error

Comment: You're trying to set your `LawSearchWindow` as its own delegate. You should be setting your Main VC as the delegate (in my example, `self` should be the main VC or whatever you have that has implemented `getResults(results: String)`). I recommend reading the [documentation on protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html) to see what you're doing wrong, as this pattern is very well documented. You can also post the code in your mainVC which creates the `LawSearchWindow` object and I can help you fix that.

Comment: My LawSearchWindow is built in IB, not in the Main VC, does that make a difference?

Comment: No, it shouldn't.

Comment: What about a embed segue between the Main VC and PVC, should that have an effect?